# Display Template: Retrieving user properties from person field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, display-template

I've been searching high and low for a couple of days for a solution, but can't find anything that fits. I've seen a lot of blogs refer to the Srch.U object and then using various methods. I've seen articles that point readers to the default item_person template. I've also seen the REST API mentioned, but am more confused than ever.

**My current setup:**

I'm using SharePoint Online. I have a very simple list called Team Members on a sub site with a few columns:

- Title (default column - contains a plain text version of the user's display -name typed in manually)
- TeamMember (People or Group currently set to Work Email so I can hook up the profile picture from Delve)
- Job Title (Text field).

I then very simply grab this information and do some stuff to make it all look pretty.

**What I would like:**

I'd like to be able to use the Person field to pull through a user's email, phone number and any other properties I might want in the future and display them in the template as required.

**My current code:**

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title'{Title}:'Title','TeamMember'{TeamMember}:'TeamMember','JobTitle'{JobTitle}:'JobTitle,JobTitleOWSTEXT'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>



    <div>
<!--#_

var Title = $getItemValue(ctx, "Title");
var TeamMember = $getItemValue(ctx, "TeamMember");
var JobTitle = $getItemValue(ctx, "JobTitle");

 _#-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <a href="https://mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx?p=_#= TeamMember =#_"><img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=_#= TeamMember =#_" alt="_#= JobTitle =#_" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <h2 class="media-heading comrole"><a style="color: #CC0000;" href="https://mydomain-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx?p=_#= TeamMember =#_">_#= Title =#_</a></h2>
                            <h2 class="media-heading comUserName" data-membersip="_#= TeamMember =#_">_#= JobTitle =#_</h2>
<p><a href="mailto:_#= TeamMember =#_">_#= TeamMember =#_</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Any help as to what option to set my person field to and how to hook into the user's profile would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Tom

Comment: Did you find any solution for this question. I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have built a web part similiar to what you are trying to build here:
Just place a content editor WP and point it to that html page (save this html code into your assets library or style library)

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:HideFromDelve msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HideFromDelve>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Contacts"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                'use strict';

                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Key Contacts')/items?$select=*&$select=Person/Title,Person/JobTitle,Person/EMail,Person/Department,Person/WorkPhone&$expand=Person/ID&$top=5",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                    success: getUserSuccess,
                    error: getUserError
                });

                function getUserSuccess(data, request) {
                    var html = [];
                    var results = data.d.results;
                    //console.log(data.d);
                    var siteCollectionURL = SP.PageContextInfo.get_siteServerRelativeUrl();
                    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
                    var image = siteCollectionURL + "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=";
                    var mysite = "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx?p=";
                    var membersPage = siteURL + "/Pages/Members.aspx";
                    var icon = siteCollectionURL + "/SiteAssets/Images/Icons/people.png";

                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            html.push("<div class='contact-item'><div class='contact-profile-image'><img src='" + image + results[i].Person.EMail + "'></div>");
                            if(results[i].Person.Title){
                                html.push("<ul class='contact-profile-details'><li class='contact-name'><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:OpenInNewTab('"+mysite+results[i].Person.EMail+"'); return false;\">" + results[i].Person.Title + "</a></li>");
                            }
                            if(results[i].Person.JobTitle){
                                html.push("<li class='contact-description'>" + results[i].Person.JobTitle + "</li>");
                            }
                            if(results[i].Expertise){
                                html.push("<li class='contact-profile-expertise'>" + "Expertise: " + results[i].Expertise + "</li>");
                            }
                            if(results[i].Person.EMail ){
                                html.push("<li class='contact-email'><a href='" + "mailto:" + results[i].Person.EMail + "'>" + results[i].Person.EMail + "</a></li>");
                            }
                            if(results[i].Person.WorkPhone){
                                html.push("<li class=''>" + "Office Phone: " + results[i].Person.WorkPhone + "</li>");
                            }
                                html.push("</ul>");
                            html.push("<hr>");
                                        }
                                    if(i = results.length){
                                        html.push("<div  class='AllLink'><img src='" + icon + "'><a href='"+membersPage+"'>ALL TEAM MEMBERS</a></div>");                    


                    }
                    $('#Contacts').append(html.join(''));

                }


                function getUserError(error) {
//                  alert("error");
                    html.push("<div>Please refresh the page and try again</div>");
                }
        });

            function OpenInNewTab(url) {
              var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
              win.focus();
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. That's not quite what I'm looking for though. I already have a solution in place - I just need to enhance it slightly. :)